# Taylor series of the upper incomplete gamma function

Tags: special-functions

What is the taylor series of the upper incomplete gamma function? I need it to approximate a difficult integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taylor series of the non-normalised upper incomplete gamma function is
$$\Gamma(a,z)
= \int_{z}^{\infty}t^{a-1}e^{-t}\,dt\\
= \Gamma(a)-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}z^{a+k}}{k!(a+k)}
=\Gamma(a)\left(1-z^ae^{-z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{\Gamma(a+k+1)}\right),$$
see e.g. http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7.E3. If you need the normalised version, you have
$$Q(a, z)
= \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_{z}^{\infty}t^{a-1}e^{-t}\,d t
=\frac{\Gamma(a,z)}{\Gamma(a)}\cdot$$